# The type or namespace name 'Server' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
The type or namespace name 'Server' could not be found (are you missing a 
using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What are the namespaces or assemblies to be added to counter this error.Similar error is thrown when I am Using `ServerConnection` Class.

Comment: Well do you have a reference in your project to `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` (the assembly where these classes live)?

Comment: `Add the Reference` by Right clicking the `Reference` in your Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to the below assembly

> **Namespace**:  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common
>
> **Assembly**:  Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo (in Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll)

[Find more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.aspx)

Comment: did not resolved issue for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Find the source file where this error happens. It will likely to contain a namespace using statement, like

```
//make sure this dll is copied to the deployment machine
using Foo.Server;  // <=====

namespace MyProject
{
    public class Bar { } 
}
```

- Check if the reference to the particular library is added to the project
- Make sure it is *not* referenced from the */bin*, instead use a */lib* folder or *GAC*
- Check the properties of the library and set it *Copy Local* to *true*